# What values of x would give rise to possible factors?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, cubics

This is probably going to be straightforward, but given

$P(x)=2x^3−3x^2+4x+3$

Which values of $x$ will give rise to possible factors?

I have the following alternatives (More than one can be correct):

a) −1

b) 1

c) −3

d) 3

e) $\frac{−1}{2}$

f) $\frac{1}{2}$

g) $\frac{-3}{2}$

h) $\frac{-3}{2}$

Using the **factor theorem**, I've decided to use $\frac{P(x)}{2}$.

Hence, my $d$ will become $\frac{d}{2}$ and I chose what would be the factors of $d$ do make tests, for instance: $\{\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{-3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\}$

I've found one solution with $x=\frac{-1}{2}$, which yields the factor $(x + \frac{1}{2})$

Which gives me

$(x + \frac{1}{2})(2x^2 -4x +6)$

Then I can transform that to $P(x)$ to get me back to

$(2x+1)(x^2 -2x +3)$

It has two factors: one linear in the form  $(ax+b)$, both integers, and one quadratic. The quadratic factor cannot be further factorised.

Now I don't understand why none of the alternatives above is working for me? For me the correct answer should be $e)$ only as no other value brings me zero. But perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Comment: You have it right...$-\frac 12$ is the only rational root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking you **to select** which **one** out of all the answers is correct. So as you've stated the correct choice is e).

It's a multiple choice question! Good job :)

Comment: Thanks! It seems like there's a glitch in the platform I'm using to learn. A Q&A feature should be norm for every lecture in these MOOCs :)